Center manifold including nonlinear functions
I'm dealing with a dynamical system with nonlinear functions. I want to apply center manifold reduction. I use the following steps which has been mentioned in Wiggins' text book.
After transforming the fixed point to origin and transforming to eigenspace, I will be left with a polynomial equation to solve.
$$
Dh(u,\mu)(A u + \exp(\beta_1 u + \beta_2 h(u, \mu)+\mu) = B h(u, \mu) + \exp(\beta_1 u + \beta_2 h(u, \mu)+\mu)
$$
With $A=\frac{-1}{\tau_1}$ and $B=\frac{-1}{\tau_2}$ simple linear terms.
Since $h(u,\mu)$ is a polynomial of $a_1 u^2 + a_2 u \mu + a_3 \mu^2$, It become difficult to solve the system since in one hand we have the polynomials and in another hand we have exponential nonlinearity.
I plugged this system to software (sympy) to solve and I got the following answer:
$ h(u, \mu) = 0 \cdot u^2 + 0 \cdot u\mu - \frac{W\left(- b_{2} t_{2} e^{I\mu + b_{1} u}\right)}{b_{2} I\mu^2} \mu^2$
The reason that it's surprising is that now $a_3$ which should have been a function of parameters $a=f(\beta_1, \beta_2, \tau_1, \tau_2) $ is now a function of variables too, $a=f(u, \mu, \beta_1, \beta_2, \tau_1, \tau_2)$.
So with this introduction, I have the following questions:

First, can you equate a polynomial set to a nonlinear function set or you need to use Taylor expansion for your nonlinear function?

Second, in center manifold reduction, are you allowed to have your polynomial constant as a function of variables too? (or it needs to be a function of parameters only).


